# Existence of symmetric subsets

Tags: connectedness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a nonempty open connected subset of a (real) topological vector space $X$.

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists a nonempty open connected set $B\subseteq A$ such that $B$, in addition, is symmetric (i.e., $B=-B$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,1)$ is a nonempty open connected subset of $\mathbb R$ and it does not contain  any nonempty symmetric set.

Comment: Obviously I forgot an hypothesis. Nevermind, I will ask it in another question ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226780/existence-of-a-symmetric-subset-b-subseteq-a-such-that-2a-a-subseteq-8a )