# Existence of a symmetric subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $2A-A\subseteq 8A$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a nonempty open connected subset of a (real) topological vector space $X$ such that $$2A-A \subseteq 8A$$ (for instance one could take $A=(-1,2)$).

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists a nonempty open connected set $B\subseteq A$ such that $B$, in addition, is symmetric (i.e., $B=-B$)?

Comment: Have you proved it for $X=\Bbb R$ at least?

Comment: @AdamChalumeau The hypotheses imply $0\in A$.

Comment: @logarithm Do they? Do you have a proof of this? If so, then $A \cap -A$ is a good choice for $B$.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau No, I don't have a proof. What I know is: there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $0$ (iterating $\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}x \in A$ for all $x \in A$) and, as Theo Bendit observed, if $0 \in A$ then the claim would follow (at least for normed vector spaces $X$).

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti this is true if $X=\Bbb R$. If $A=(a,b)$ then $2A-A\subset 8A\iff (2a-b,2b-a)\subset(8a,8b)\iff 6b+a\leq0~\text{and}~6 a+b\geq0$, so $7a<0$ and $7b>0$.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau Why $A=(a,b)$?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Those are the only connected open sets of $\mathbb{R}$, and of a general $A$ intersected with a line in a general tvs.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti ok if $a$ or $b$ is infinite then $2A-A=\Bbb R$, which means $A$ must be $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ops, you are right. I don't know why I was using implicitly "locally connected" in my mind.

Comment: Actually, I take it back: $A \cap -A$ may not be connected.

Comment: @TheoBendit All elements of $A\cap(-A)$ are path-connected to $0$.

Comment: @logarithm I posted an answer showing $B$ exists, which implies that $0\in B\subseteq A$, so $0\in A\cap(-A)$, and clearly $A\cap(-A)$ is open. Do you have a proof that $A\cap(-A)$ is connected or path-connected? (In particular, in view of the preceding comment by Theo Bendit that $A\cap(-A)$ may not be connected.) For now I can't rule out either option. Thank you very much, I would appreciate more details, thank you

Comment: @logarithm No, not necessarily. Their union would be connected. Consider, in $\Bbb{R}^n$, the set $$A = \{(x, y) : y \ge 0, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1\} \cup \{(x, y) : y \ge 0, (x + 1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$$ Then $A \cap -A = \{(-2, 0), (0, 0), (2, 0)\}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Indeed $A\cap-A$ is not connected in your comment, but this particular $A$ that you describe is not open and $2A-A\not\subseteq8A$. I wonder if requiring that $A$ is open and $2A-A\subseteq8A$ (as in the OP) might perhaps imply that $A\cap-A$ is connected.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I edited my answer to make it more complete and easier to read. I think in the title of your question it would be correct to say "...given that $2A-A\subseteq8A$", rather than "...such that $2A-A\subseteq8A$". Finally I wonder if there was any particular motivation for this problem, where did it come from? Thank you!

Comment: @Mirko The example was really supposed to demonstrate why $A \cap (-A)$ may not be connected, even though $0 \in A$ and $A$ is connected. An open example is easy enough too; just add (in the sense of Minkowski sum) an open ball of radius $1/3$ to $A$, and the intersection should still be disconnected (I don't want to compute the exact intersection). However, I agree that $2A - A \subseteq 8A$ (probably) does not hold here. Note that, if $0 \in A$, $A$ is open in a normed linear space, then $A$ always contains an open ball around $0$, which is open, connected, and symmetric.

Comment: @Mirko Sure: There are some results in the context of functional equations which use hypotheses of the type "If $A$ is a nonempty open connected set such that $\sum_{i\le n} \alpha_iA \subseteq A$, given $\alpha_i$ nonzero reals, and (a functional equation holds for all variables $A$) then (the same functional equation holds on the whole $X$)". Considering that the claim is independent of $A$, the existence of such subset (here, it is only a special case) would ensure that it is sufficient to set wlog the hypothesis only for positive coefficients $\alpha_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got many ideas from the comments, but I had to verify the details, and to modify and add some elements to convince myself that the answer is yes (as shown below).

So we have $\frac A8\subseteq \frac A4 - \frac A8\subseteq A$ (hence $\frac A8\subseteq A$, also $\frac A{64}\subseteq \frac A8$, and, by induction, $\frac A{8^n}\subseteq A$ for all $n\ge1$). Since $A$ is open, it is not difficult to see that if $C$ is the closure of $A$ then also $\frac A4 - \frac C8=\frac A4 - \frac A8\subseteq A$ (the details are provided in a corollary near the end). If $a\in A$ then the sequence $\frac a{8^n}$ converges to $0$ (I believe even in general TVS (yes, reference provided in a comment below by OP)), so $0\in C$. Hence $\frac A4=\frac A4-0 \subseteq\frac A4 - \frac C8=\frac A4 - \frac A8\subseteq A$. 
So we have:

(i) $\frac A{32} \subseteq \frac A4$ because $\frac A8\subseteq A$,

(ii) $\frac A{32} \subseteq \frac A8$ because $\frac A4 \subseteq A$, and

(iii) $\frac A4 - \frac A8\subseteq A$.

Using the above we get 
$\frac A{32} - \frac A{32} \subseteq \frac A4 - \frac A8 \subseteq A$. Thus the set $B=\frac A{32} - \frac A{32}$ works. Clearly it is symmetric, and it is open and connected: It is connected since it is the continuous image of $A\times A$ under the subtraction function (and division by $32$), and the product space $A\times A$ is connected since the factors are.

Here are some details on the condition that 
$\frac A4\subseteq A$, which was used in the above proof. One way to prove it is without 
a reference to the closure $C$ of $A$, as follows.

Claim. $\frac A4 \subseteq A$ (or equivalently, $2A\subseteq8A$).

Proof. Take any $a\in A$, we need to show that $2a\in 8A$. Since $A$ is open, there is $n$ such that $a+\frac a{2\cdot8^n}\in A$. Then $2a=2(a+\frac a{2\cdot8^n})-\frac a{8^n}\in 2A-A\subseteq 8A$. This completes the proof of the Claim.

Here is an alternative way to show that 
$2A\subseteq8A$. Show that $2A-A=2A-C$ 
(where $A$ is open and $C$ is the closure of $A$). (Then, since $0\in C$ we get that 
$2A\subseteq2A-C=2A-A\subseteq8A$.)

Lemma. If $U$ is open and $K$ is arbitrary then 
$U+\overline K= U+K$ (where $\overline K$ is the 
closure of $K$).

Proof. Pick any $p\in U+\overline K$. Then 
$p=q+r$ for some $q\in U$ and $r\in\overline K$. 
Since $U$ is open, there exists a symmetric neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $q+V\subseteq U$. Pick $s\in(r+V)\cap K$. Then $v=s-r\in V$ so $-v\in-V=V$ and $q-v\in U$, hence $p=q+r=q-v+r+v=(q-v)+s\in U+K$. Thus $U+\overline K\subseteq U+K$ and $U+\overline K=U+K$.

Corollary. If $A$ is open and $C$ is the closure of $A$ then $2A-C=2A-A$. (So, if, in addition, $2A-A\subseteq8A$ where $A$ is open and nonempty then $2A\subseteq2A-C=2A-A\subseteq8A$, using that $0\in C$ for the first inclusion.)

Proof. Use the above Lemma with $U=2A$ and $K=-A$.

Discussion. So the inclusion $2A\subseteq8A$ was given two different proofs, one direct, and another using the closure $C$ of $A$, along with the above lemma and corollary (providing a quicker approach, at least to me). I did not know (beforehand) if $0\in A$, and did not use it in my proof (though it eventually follows from $0\in\frac A{32}-\frac A{32}=B\subseteq A$), and I do not know if $A\cap(-A)$ must be connected (assuming that $A$ is open and $2A-A\subseteq8A$). An example when $A\cap(-A)$ need not be connected was provided by another user in the comments above, $A$ is the union of the two closed upper semicircles in the plane, of radius $1$ with centers at $(\pm1,0)$, but this $A$ is not open and $2A-A\not\subseteq8A$. (The two semicircles could easily be made open, by ``thickening'' them a little, but it is not clear to me at present if we could also get $2A-A\subseteq8A$,  and yet to have $A\cap(-A)$ disconnected). 
One more comment: If $0\in A$ (where $A$ is open) and if we work in a locally connected space, then the connected component of $A\cap(-A)$ containing $0$ would be open and symmetric (so this component could play the role of $B$). But, we need to assume some extra condition 
(e.g. $2A-A\subseteq8A$) to show that $0\in A$, 
and even if we knew that $0\in A$, it might not be immediately clear how $A\cap(-A)$ would possibly help, if the space is not locally connected. (I would be curious to see a proof - if there is one - based on the use of $A\cap(-A)$, showing that either it is connected, or that it contains a connected, open symmetric set.)

Comment: About your question in brackets, the answer is positive, see Theorem 1.15.a in Rudin's "Functional Analysis": let $V$ be any neighborhood of $0$, then $\bigcup_n nV=X$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I think I fixed the details in my proof (with or without the use of the closure $C$ of $A$). So now I know $0\in A$ since $0\in B\subseteq A$. I do not know if $A\cap(-A)$ is connected (and I am curious, but will leave it for now). Clearly $A\cup(-A)$ is connected.

Comment: The proof depends on the choice of the coefficients, however I find it very nice.